# .htaccess rewrite works when two params, but cant read first one with slash after

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know this type of problem is asked a lot but I havent been able to find a resolution to this.

My .htaccess code rewrites it so that the first param is the page, then up to 3 after that are param1, param2, and param3. This works fine, for example when the url is "localhost/portal/dashboard" . But when the url is "localhost/portal/dashboard/" (The extra slash), it doesnt work and gives a 404 error.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&param1=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&param1=$2&param2=$3 [L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but adding an optional slash to the end of your rewrite matchers might work, like so:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&param1=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&param1=$2&param2=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!